# Why can't I create a QSP in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I've just started playing dwarf fortress. I designated a stockpile to store woods in order, and then removed that stockpile. After that, I marked all woods in the rectangle area as `Dump items` using <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>, and created a single-tile zone near the entrance.

However, dwarves don't react to my order, and all woods remain unmoved. I've checked and all dwarves have `Refuse Hauling` labor enabled. What's wrong?

[image]
<sub>As you can see, all woods has been marked as `Dump`.</sub>

[image]
<sub>This is the quantum stockpile I want to create.</sub>

[image]
<sub>These dwarves should be hauling woods, but they aren't.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is really common among players that haven't played DF much. There is a setting (I think accessed via [O]rders, [R]efuse, [O]utside) that turns on and off refuse hauling if outside. Refuse hauling only applies by default underground or inside your fortress. Don't ask me why the refuse hauling default works that way.

Comment: AFAICT, it's a left-over from earlier game versions, before burrows and mass-designation for forbid and dump were introduced. Way back then, the only way to keep dorfs inside was to: 1. not have anything important outside, 2. manually mark crap as forbidden, or 3. use the [o]rders menu to disable dumped stuff outside, and the [F]orbidden sub-menu to auto-forbid fired ammo, dead people's clothes and corpses, etc. When getting a sudden gobo invasion, or a titan attack, this meant the difference between losing a few unluck dorfs, or losing the whole fort.