# Why don't my dwarves haul corpses to corpse stockpile?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

As you can see, my fortress is filled with miasma, which is generated by lots of rotten dwarf corpses. I have a corpse stockpile outside and one idle dwarf who has `Refuse Hauling` labor enabled. I've waited for quite a while, but he is still under `no job` state. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are your dwarves allowed to leave the fortress? Is there a valid path to the corpse-stockpile? Is corpse hauling enabled (o->Dwarves Haul/Ignore corpses)? Are the corpses forbidden?

Comment: check the job listing to make sure the haul corpse jobs are getting queued up.

Comment: @Silent-Bob I didn't forbidden them to leave the fortress; Their path to the corpse-stockpile is unblocked; Can't see `Dwarves Haul/Ignore corpses`, but `Dwarves Dump corpses`(o->r->c) is set; None of the corpses are forbidden.

Comment: @KutuluMike Unfortunately, hauling isn't on the job list, and my question is **why** it isn't.

Comment: Consider looking at [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/268998/49753) if the corpses are outside. Also the gather/ignore bodies is in the top of the orders menu tree, not under refuse. So (o->g).

Comment: @Silent-Bob: I like your concept of a corpse-stockpile. I'm sure there must be a use for dead dwarfs, so let us stockpile them for that future need.

Comment: @Mark Ripley i bury them, of course. But that was not what OP was aking for and who am i to tell him how he should play his game ;) (also i didn't have time to write a good answer which would also explain burial, like you did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What! You are dumping dead dwarves on your garbage heap? You insensitive cad! Dwarves like to be [buried](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Coffin), in coffins (carpenter/wood) or Sarcophagi (mason/stone). Once you make some and install them in a tomb room, your dwarves may bury the dead dwarves there. Even though this may not solve your miasma problem from rotting things other than dwarf bodies, this may solve your dwarf body problem, since miasma doesn't occur once the bodies are in a coffin. I believe that by default all your dwarves have the burial labor turned on, and the weird DF behavior regarding hauling garbage outside the fortress doesn't apply to the burial labor.

Update: apparently dwarves refuse to treat dwarf bodies or body-parts as garbage in the most recent versions, so your regular garbage hauling should work to stop miasma on things other than dead dwarf bodies, but you will need a tomb for dead dwarfs.